# What are the conversion constructors

Tags: c++, constructor

```
class Complex
{
private:
double real;
double imag;

public:
// Default constructor
Complex(double r = 0.0, double i = 0.0) : real(r), imag(i) {}

// A method to compare to Complex numbers
bool operator == (Complex rhs) {
   return (real == rhs.real && imag == rhs.imag)? true : false;
}
};

int main()
{
// a Complex object
Complex com1(3.0, 0.0);

if (com1 == 3.0)
   cout << "Same";
else
   cout << "Not Same";
 return 0;
}
```

Output:
Same

Why this code gives output as Same, how the conversion constructor in working here, please explain, Many many thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A conversion constructor is any non-`explicit` constructor callable with one argument. In your code sample, as the `Complex` constructor provides default values for its parameters, it can be called with a single argument (say `3.0`). And since such constructor is not marked `explicit`, then it is a valid conversion constructor.

When you do `com1 == 3.0` --given that there is no `operator ==` between `Complex` and `double`-- a conversion constructor is invoked. So your code is equivalent to this:

```
if( com1 == Complex(3.0) )
```

Comment: Thanx a lot for providing solution

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the compiler sees the `==` operator being used on a `complex` object and tries to find a way to make it work. There's only one `operator==` and it requires a `complex` argument. Since there's a `complex` constructor that takes a double and is not marked `explicit`, it uses that to generate a temporary `complex` object which it then passes to `operator==`.