# When does copy constructor get called

Tags: c++

I studied that during initialization of object, for example

```
string s = "Hello world";
```

If RHS is implicitly convertible to LHS type object, then Copy Constructor would be called. But I have a friend who is pretty sure that constructor which takes `char` pointer as an argument would be called.But I told him that constructor with `char`pointer would be called only in cases as below

```
string s("Hello world");
```

Is that correct?

Comment: Also be aware that if `s` was not defined in the same line, it would use the `std::string::operator=(const char*)` function, and not any constructor at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Doing

```
string s = "Hello world";
```

is equivalent to

```
string s( string( "Hello world" ) );
```

so both the constructor taking `char const*` and the *copy-constructor* are called. However, the standard allows *copy-elision* where the *copy-constructor* call is *elided* (not done).

Comment: Had to go to your [conversion constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905866/what-are-the-conversion-constructors) to understand everything. So constructor with `constant char pointer` is the conversion constructor here right?Thnx for both the amazing answers.

Comment: @tez: Yes, the constructor taking a `char const*` is a _conversion constructor_.

Answer (score 3):

Yes and no. Both are called.

```
string s = "Hello world";
```

This is **copy initialization**. It calls the conversion constructor and constructs a temporary `string` from `"Hellow world"` and then uses that temporary with the copy constructor to construct `s`. (*subject to optimizations*)

```
string s("Hello world");
```

Is **direct initialization** and calls the conversion constructor directly, constructing `s` from `"Hello world"`.

Comment: IIRC the first one doesn't have to call the copy constructor, only require it is available. Not sure though.

Comment: @Pubby yes, copy elision is possible.

Comment: @Pubby: The semantics are as-if it was called. The compiler is free to elide the copy.

Comment: @dribeas not even as-if. copy elision may change the meaning.