# A bit of help understanding constructors, operator overloads, destructors, etc

Tags: c++, class, object, constructor

so I'm a C++ beginner and I have a question.

Let's say we have a class Grades.

From what I've learned so far a destructor would look like

```
~Grades();
```

a copy constructor:

```
Grades(const Grades & );
```

an << operator:

```
ostream & operator << (ostream & os, const Grades & g);
```

Are these correct?

How would a regular constructor look like? What about a conversion constructor ?

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO and nice that you took up C++ programming. One thing though, answers to questions like these [are](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_constructor_destructor.htm) [not](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/) [hard](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors) to find on Google [or](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15077788/3492835) [on](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10905866/3492835) [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Regular default constructor, provided by compiler, will look like below and it will internally call the `base class` constructors if it is derived from any class. And later for data members having user defined type, it will call their respective default constructors in the order of their declaration.

```
Grades();
```

The conversion constructors are something you will have to define, and they will look like

```
Grade(const T&)
```

If you want conversion function,

```
 Grade operator=(const T&)
```

The only `destructor` you could have is suppose to de-initialize the object by calling respective `destructors` if user defined data members and then for base classes, exactly in reverse order what default compiler provided constructor would provide.